# GetDC() function in QWidget in Qt 5.0.1

Tags: qt5

I rewrite application from Qt 4.8 to 5.0.1 and I have big trouble. In Qt 5.0.1 version there is no `GetDC()` function (with no argument). `GetDC(hwnd)` exist but I have no `hwnd`. What should I do? Please help. On google there is no information about it.

Comment: I solved my problem. HWND hwnd = (HWND)this->winId(); and GetDC(hwnd);

Comment: You might add this as an answer instead of a comment. You can then mark it as answered. You get extra points for it too